# math::pose and raySensor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've a question about pose management and in particular regarding the world pose of a RaySensor calculation

the line 265 in RaySensor.cc
calculate the world position of the raySensor as

```
this->parentEntity->GetWorldPose() + this->GetPose()
```

while in other part of code, e.g., IMU use (at line 140-141 of ImuSensor.cc)

```
math::Pose parentEntityPose = this->parentEntity->GetWorldPose();
math::Pose imuPose = this->pose + parentEntityPose;
```

Now, I've done some experiment with the math::Pose class and I think that the second way is the right one, since pose composition uses a postfix notation. So, imho this is a bug in the RaySensor implementation. Someone have experienced problems with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1636/math::pose-and-raysensor/) by [SImone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/207/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You are correct. Thanks for the bug report. Here is a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/351/fix-pose-computation-in-raysensor/diff).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0